# How do I prevent the default submission of forms loaded via Ajax in this Laravel 8 app?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have made a [blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0) in Laravel 8. I am currently working on adding *comment replies* via jQuery (v3.5.0) AJAX.

In `comment-form.blade.php` I have:

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--success">
    Your comment is pending
  </div>

  <div class="alert-box-ajax alert-box alert-box--error">
    Failed to add comment!
  </div>

  <form class="commentForm" method="post" action="{{ route('comment.submit') }}" autocomplete="off" novalidate>
    @csrf
      <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="{{ isset($article->id) ? $article->id : $article_id }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comment->id ?? '' }}">

        <div class="message form-field">
            <textarea name="msg" id="message" class="h-full-width" placeholder="Your Message" required></textarea>

            @error('msg')
            <p class="help-block text-danger">{{ $message }}</p>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <br>
        <input name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn--primary btn-wide btn--large h-full-width" value="Add Comment" type="submit">
      </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

The template above, of course, repeats for every comment, so that replies can be added to any of them.

Replies are submitted via jQuery Ajax:

```
$(".commentForm").each(function () {
    var form = $(this);
    form.validate({
        errorElement: "p",
        errorClass: "help-block text-danger",

        submitHandler: function (_form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $fields = form.find("textarea"),
                url = form.attr("action"),
                data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                  if (response.status === 'success') {
                    form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                        .slideDown(250)
                        .delay(2500)
                        .slideUp(250);
                  $fields.val("");
                  } else {
                    form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                        .slideDown(250)
                        .delay(2500)
                        .slideUp(250);
                  }
                },
                error: function (err) {    
                  console.log(err);
                },
            });
        },
    });
});
```

#### The problem

There is an option to load a maximum of 10 comemnts for each post initially, the rest being loaded on page scroll, via an Ajax call.

When this option is active, the script above fails to prevent the default behavior of the forms loaded via Ajax.

**!Note:** The issue is not the submit event, but its *prevention*.

#### Questions

1. What causes this issue?
2. What is the most reliable solution to the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @Pippo My case is very particular: it has an `each` loop and, for each element, a submit event.

Comment: In fact: you have to set the event handler on the parent of the forms, not on the forms themselves

Comment: Pippo is correct.  On page load, the JS you've shown adds event handlers for each `.commentForm` *which exists at page load*.  When more forms are later on dynamically added to the page, the existing event handlers do not apply to them.  So when you click submit, there is no `event.preventDefault()` happening, and the form submits normally, as you are seeing.

Comment: The most common solution is to delegate the event handler to something that exists at page load.  See [*Direct and delegated event handlers*](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), specifically the paragraph beginning "**Delegated event handlers**".

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Not the problem here but also note you have `id="submit"`, and `id="message"` duplicated for every form.  That's invalid HTML - `id`s must be unique on the page.  If you ever try to use those elements with JS, this problem will bite you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is due to the fact that the jQuery .each() function and .validate() method are only applied to the elements that are present in the DOM at the time the code is run. This means that any elements (in your case, the comment forms) that are added to the DOM later (via AJAX) will not have these methods applied to them.

To solve this issue, you can use event delegation. Event delegation allows you to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

Here's how you can modify your jQuery code to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.commentForm', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var $fields = form.find("textarea"),
        url = form.attr("action"),
        data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'success') {
                form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                    .slideDown(250)
                    .delay(2500)
                    .slideUp(250);
                $fields.val("");
            } else {
                form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                    .slideDown(250)
                    .delay(2500)
                    .slideUp(250);
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {    
            console.log(err);
        },
    });
});
```

Here is what I think. New code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.commentForm', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    form.validate({
      errorElement: "p",
      errorClass: "help-block text-danger",
      rules: {
        msg: "required",
      },
      messages: {
        msg: "Enter a comment",
      }
    });

    // Check if the form is valid
    if (!form.valid()) {
      return;
    }

    var $fields = form.find("textarea"),
      url = form.attr("action"),
      data = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "post",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'success') {
          form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
            .slideDown(250)
            .delay(2500)
            .slideUp(250);
          $fields.val("");
        } else {
          form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
            .slideDown(250)
            .delay(2500)
            .slideUp(250);
        }
      },
      error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      },
    });
});
```

Comment: What about validation, though?

Comment: Preventing the default submission works, but there is no form validation in your solution.

Comment: I don't figure out that.

Comment: Check my answer again, I update a new code there.

Answer (score 2):

That would work no matter how many forms for each comment as each form would belong to single comment.

```
$(document).on("submit", ".commentForm", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    form.validate({
      errorElement: "p",
      errorClass: "help-block text-danger",

      submitHandler: function (_form, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $fields = form.find("textarea"),
          url = form.attr("action"),
          data = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
          dataType: "json",
          type: "post",
          url: url,
          data: data,
          cache: false,
          success: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'success') {
              form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                .slideDown(250)
                .delay(2500)
                .slideUp(250);
              $fields.val("");
            } else {
              form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                .slideDown(250)
                .delay(2500)
                .slideUp(250);
            }
          },
          error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
          },
        });
      },
    });
  });
```

Comment: It does not work. Probably because of `var form = $(this)`.

Comment: That will work as `var form = $(this);` would fetch this entire form elements.
https://jsfiddle.net/fy2nm941/

Comment: I tried it. It does not work.

Comment: What error it gives on which line? It would be great if you would share render comments section so I can run that code and try to fix

Comment: There is no error, the post just does not happen. The comment replies are **not** added for Ajax-loaded forms. You can check the **[GitHub repo](https://github.com/Ajax30/BraveCMS-2.0)** for more details if you want.

Comment: It does not work. The comets are _not_ submitted at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has already been explained in the comments.  The Javascript you've shown runs at page load, and selectors there will only ever match elements which exist at page load.  If you dynamically add elements later on, that Javascript does not run agian, those selectors don't match them.

In this case, it means `$(".commentForm")` matches only those forms with that class which exist at page load, so only those forms get the validation code applied.  When you later add new `$(".commentForm")`s to the page, that JS which ran at page load does not run again for the new forms, and they have no validation at all.  Submitting those forms does not run any of the Javascript here, they just submit normally, which is what you are seeing.

To get around this, you could make your validation a function that you can call at any time, for eg:

```
// Function to initialise validation on the passed form element.  
// $form is a jQuery object.  Note you now need to use $form to
// reference the form being validated, eg $form.find("textarea"), 
// $form.closest(), etc, inside the function.
function commentFormValidation($form) {
    $form.validate({
        // ... your validation code. 
        submitHandler: function (_form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let $fields = $form.find("textarea");
            $.ajax({
                // ...
            });
        },
    });
}

// At page load, apply validation to each form that exists at that time
$(".commentForm").each(function () {
    commentFormValidation($(this));
});
```

Now you can dynamically add validation to a new form when it is added to the DOM.  You haven't shown us the code which adds new forms, but for demonstration purposes let's say you're cloning some master form template, maybe something like this:

```
// Pseudo/simplified code, this is just for demonstration
let $template = $('#commentForm-template');   // some master template
let $copy = $template.clone();                // create a copy
$copy.appendTo('.someContainer');             // add it to DOM somewhere
commentFormValidation($copy);                 // add validation to it
```

Whatever the code looks like, the only important part you need to do is to call the new validation function on the new form:

```
commentFormValidation($newFormJQueryObject);
```

Similar questions for reference:

- [Jquery Validate on dynamic form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255958/jquery-validate-on-dynamic-form)
- [Jquery - Validating only one form out of multiple forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092806/jquery-validating-only-one-form-out-of-multiple-forms)
- [Using the jquery validation plugin on a form that is generated using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678869/using-the-jquery-validation-plugin-on-a-form-that-is-generated-using-ajax)

Alterntively, you could also do this using event delegation, though it is a bit trickier, and IMO doesn't feel as neat a solution.

First, we need to attach an event handler to a selector that exists at page load, and will be the parent of all forms, current and future.  Let's call it `.someContainer`.  Next we filter the selector to match only your forms:

```
$('.someContainer').on('submit', '.commentForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
```

Now any `submit` event that happens inside that container will trigger this handler - even for forms that are added after page load.  There's no need to add separate code to handle the forms that exist at page load, this will catch all of them.

Next, we obviously need to add the code which initialises the validation on the form that has just been submitted.  We can do this with our existing `commentFormValidation()` function:

```
$('.someContainer').on('submit', '.commentForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    commentFormValidation($(this));
    // ...
```

But there's a problem.  Submitting the form adds the validation, but it won't actually *run* the validation.  So the first time you submit the form, nothing will happen, because the submit action has been intercepted by this handler, validation added, ... and that's all.  It won't actually run the validation until you submit the form again!

So we need to manually run the validation after it has been added.  You can do that by calling [the `.valid()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) on the form - though it doesn't work here, I'm not sure why.

So instead we can just manually re-submit the form, which will run the validation.

Here's a working snippet demonstrating this delegation approach.  Check the console output to see the various stages happening.

```js
function commentFormValidation($form) {
    $form.validate({
        rules: {
            foo: 'required'
        },
        submitHandler: function (_form, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('submitHandler running');
        },
    });
}

$('.someContainer').on('submit', '.commentForm', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('event handler running');

    // Initialise validation on this form
    commentFormValidation($(this));

    // Manually run the validation on this form - not sure why, does 
    // not work
    // $(this).valid();
    
    // Manually re-submit the form to trigger validation
    $(this).submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<div class="someContainer">
    <form class="commentForm">
        <input type="text" name="foo">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think there are parenthesis that do not match.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Did you try either option?

Comment: No, it is missing code.

Comment: I'm curious what you think is missing?  I'm doubly curious because the answer you have accepted is completely missing validation, which is really the whole point of your question ... what is my (2) answer(s) missing that is worse than missing validation?! :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix is to differentiate between initialized and not initialized content. Let's create a function, wrap it around your code and let's make sure we slightly modify your code to initialize the uninitialized elements:

```
function initializeForms() {
    $(".commentForm:not(.initialized)").each(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        form.addClass("initialized"); //We initialized your form, so we mark it as such
        form.validate({
            errorElement: "p",
            errorClass: "help-block text-danger",

            submitHandler: function (_form, event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $fields = form.find("textarea"),
                    url = form.attr("action"),
                    data = form.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "post",
                    url: url,
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                      if (response.status === 'success') {
                        form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--success").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                        .slideDown(250)
                        .delay(2500)
                        .slideUp(250);
                    $fields.val("");
                    } else {
                    form.closest(".form-wrapper").find(".alert-box--error").slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250)
                        .slideDown(250)
                        .delay(2500)
                        .slideUp(250);
                  }
                },
                error: function (err) {    
                  console.log(err);
                },
            });
        },
    });
});
}
```

Make sure that you call this function at page load as well as when your "next content" AJAX finished and you appended the new forms.

EDIT

You will also need to be careful, because if the `innerHTML` of a container is changed, then all event listeners are destroyed. So you will need to test whether your first elements still work when you load the next 10. If so, then my initial solution will work. If not, then you can change the initial line to `$(".commentForm:not(.initialized)").each(function () {` and remove the `form.addClass("initialized");` line.

EDIT2

Here's a working example of creating the events and recreating them after the .innerHTML` of the container changed:

```js
function customSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.currentTarget.querySelector("input").value = "clicked me";
}

function customGroupSubmit(container) {
    for (let form of container.querySelectorAll("form")) {
        form.addEventListener("submit", customSubmit);
    }
}

let container = document.querySelector(".container");

customGroupSubmit(container);

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    let template = `<div class="commentForm"><form><input type="submit" value="click me"></form></div>`;
    template = template + template + template;
    container.innerHTML += template;
    customGroupSubmit(container);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="commentForm"><form><input type="submit" value="click me"></form></div>
    <div class="commentForm"><form><input type="submit" value="click me"></form></div>
    <div class="commentForm"><form><input type="submit" value="click me"></form></div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="add" value="add">
```

Comment: Why is there a need for a named `initializeForms()` function?

Comment: I tried it. It does not work.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir the named function was created to make sure it's reusable. Can you tell me how was it not working? Did you get errors? Did it not execute?

Comment: The comment reply is not submitted.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir edited my answer, added a working example